# Set each 2 rows to another color

Tags: html, css

This is my current table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>a</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>b</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>c</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>d</td>|
   </tr>
</table>
```

now I want the first two rows to have a red background color, and the next two rows a blue color.

Comment: Study `table` and `CSS`

Comment: just use inline CSS styles

Comment: This might be helpful: [:nth-child | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

Comment: @Simon Jensen Thanks. I have little bit CSS knowledge. I know how to change the color for even and odd rows. but I dont know how to change the color for first odd and even and next odd and even....

Comment: Why people are giving  down vote I don't know. What is wrong in the question?

Answer (score 2):

[`nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) allows you to target each element using the sequence in which they occur. Special selections like first two elements requires `nth-child(-n+2)` and last two elements require `nth-last-child(-n+2)`

```css
tr:nth-child(1),
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(3),
tr:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
tr:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

for the first two row:
css:

```
table tr:not(:nth-child(n+3)) {
    background: red;
}
```

and for the lasts:
css:

```
table tr:nth-child(n+3) {
    background: blue;
}
```